# group by and concatenate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df with `frame`, `m_label`, and `details` so all of them can be duplicated, in same `frame` may be different labels with different details, but you need to know `m_label`+`details` have a constant pattern of several option for example Findings may be PL or DV , so "Findings PL start" always have "Findings PL end", except BBPS, it may be start in `details` as 3 and end as 2 or same number.   In final I need to know which label when it start (for example Action IR, start in `frame` 31) and when it end (end as Action IR in `frame` 101).
That my input:

```
  frame m_label   details
    0   BBPS      3
    0   BBPS      start
    0   Findings  DV
    0   Findings  start
    0   Findings  DV
    0   Findings  end
    31  Actions   IR
    31  Actions   start
    99  BBPS      2
    99  Findings  PL
    99  Findings  start
    99  BBPS      end
    99  Findings  PL
    99  Findings  end
    101 Action    IR
    101 Action    end
```

So I want convert this df to something like this:

```
frame m_label         details
    0   Findings.DV   start
    0  Findings.DV    end   
    0   BBPS.3        start
    31  Actions.IR    start
    99 Action.IR      end
    99 Findings.PL    start
    99  Findings.PL   end
    99  BBPS.2        end
    101  Action.IR    end
```

So I need concatenate row only without start/end and groupby(?) or transform(?) by frame..
I try this code, but then I got stuck:

```
def concat_func(x):
    if not x[1] in ['start', 'end']:
       result = x[0]+'.'+x[1]
    else:
        result=np.nan              
    return result

data_cv["concat"]=data_cv[["m_label","details"]].apply(concat_func,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I find it useful to move the start/end info to a new column, which is done by merging together the rows that have start/end on one side and the ones that don’t on the other:

```
>>> detail_type = df['details'].isin({'start', 'end'})
>>> df = pd.merge(df[~detail_type], df[detail_type].rename(columns={'details': 'detail_type'}))
>>> df
    frame   m_label details detail_type
0       0      BBPS       3       start
1       0  Findings      DV       start
2       0  Findings      DV         end
3       0  Findings      DV       start
4       0  Findings      DV         end
5      31   Actions      IR       start
6      99      BBPS       2         end
7      99  Findings      PL       start
8      99  Findings      PL         end
9      99  Findings      PL       start
10     99  Findings      PL         end
11    101    Action      IR         end
```

Now we can replace the 2 columns by their concatenated text:

```
>>> df = df.drop(columns=['m_label', 'details']).join(df['m_label'].str.cat(df['details'], sep='.'))
>>> df.drop_duplicates()
    frame detail_type      m_label
0       0       start       BBPS.3
1       0       start  Findings.DV
2       0         end  Findings.DV
5      31       start   Actions.IR
6      99         end       BBPS.2
7      99       start  Findings.PL
8      99         end  Findings.PL
11    101         end    Action.IR
```

You could even pivot to have a start and an end column:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates().pivot(columns='detail_type', index='m_label', values='frame')
detail_type    end  start
m_label                  
Action.IR    101.0    NaN
Actions.IR     NaN   31.0
BBPS.2        99.0    NaN
BBPS.3         NaN    0.0
Findings.DV    0.0    0.0
Findings.PL   99.0   99.0
```

But for that to be efficient you’ll first need to define rules that uniquely name your labels, e.g. BBPS regardless of details 2 and 3, Action / Actions always spelled the same way, etc.

Comment: Hi, in addition in column "detail_type" I have also two tags: "sp", "tr", when I just added it in dict {detail_type} and run same code, it's doesnt work, no line with m_label + "sp" or "tr". Do you know why? And what mean in pd.merge: [~]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `groupby` would help, as the order *inside* the group also matter.

Try this (since you didn't post the `df` in a copiable way, I can't test it myself):

```
df = df.assign(new_label=None).sort_values(['frame', 'm_label'])
df.loc[~df['details'].isin(['start', 'end']), 'new_label'] = df['m_label'] + '.' + df['details']
df.loc[(df['frame'] == df['frame'].shift(-1).fillna('')) & (df['m_label'] == df['m_label'].shift(-1).fillna('')) & df['details'].shift(-1).isin(['start', 'end']), 'details'] = df['details'].shift(-1).fillna('')
df = df.loc[pd.notna(df['new_label']) & df['details'].isin(['start', 'end']), ['frame', 'new_label', 'details']]
```